# How to handle this patch issue

Tags: linux, git, diff, patch

I am trying to create patch a file using diff tool.But facing an issues. 
I have created one directory named a and put original file in to it:

- a/original_file.c

I have created other directory named b and put same file with modified content in to it.

- b/original_file.c

I have copied the content of the b/original_file.c file from the internet and put it into some text editor.

After giving command `diff -Naur a b > patch_file.patch`, I can see `patch_file.patch` is generated and it has some unwanted changes (it's related to indentation).

For example:

```
 return msg (MSG_NOTIFY, &msg, senr,
-                 sizeof (struct msgotify));
+                  sizeof (struct msgotify));
```

You can see there are changed related to indentation where `sizeof (struct msgotify))` is replaced by same `sizeof (struct msgotify))` but one basis of indentation which is what we don't want.

Could anybody let me know how to get rid of this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about changes in spacing, add `-b` to the `diff` command that generates the patch.

Comment: Thansk @Jonathan ,So my command will be diff -Naur -b a b? And my new patched file will be having indendation accoring to b/original_file.c ??

Comment: Yes, you could use `diff -Naur -b` or combine it with the other flags `diff -Naurb`. Since the patch file won't contain any lines where just the spacing differs, what happens depends on how you apply the patch. Since the patch translates `a` to `b`, if you applied the patch to your file in `a`, you'd get the result with those lines containing the same spacing as in `a`, because you didn't pay attention to the difference in the spacing. If you applied the patch in reverse to the file in `b`, you'd get to the file in `a` but with the spacing as in file `b` for those lines not explicitly changed.

Comment: the option you suggested worked well for me and I can only see desired changed in patch file but when apply this patch file ,I am getting errors with was not there earlier.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  The problem may be that there were spacing changes in the context lines around the actual changes; this could upset the matching algorithm.  I don't see an option to `patch` to say 'diff created with `-b` option in effect'.  Why do you think the spacing matters so much?  It may be simpler just to go with the extra changes.  I'm not sure what to suggest; hand-surgery on the patch file could be made to work, but then you might as well apply the patch by hand in the first place — probably.

Comment: Why do you think the spacing matters so much? Well may if someone review this patch file ,it will be very difficult for him/her to see actual(desired) changes in file ,since it is a big file so for most of the time he/she will only see spaces related changes.

Comment: There's an element of an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) here.  You have a large file that you want to make local modifications to and you want to keep synchronized with an external version but there are spacing differences between the two and this causes complications.  I think you need to review what your goals are.  If the external information is important (must be synchronized), then I recommend adding your changes in a way that doesn't mess up the external material.  Follow the external coding guidelines. Isolate your changes.

Comment: Not trying to make fun of you at all.  Just trying to understand the problem, and wondering whether you were trying to do one thing as a way of achieving a solution to another problem, when there might perhaps be a better solution to the other problem...it happens.